# Postgrest OR query with JSON

Tags: postgrest

I have a json query I'm making with postgrest, that I need to accept 2 scenarios.

either the value has to be equal to "failover" or it's null (doesn't exist).

If there wasn't JSON involved, this would be a simple `or=(device_type.eq.failover,device_type.is.null)`

however... For the life of me, I can't get a query with OR and JSON to work together...

`event->labels->>device_type=eq.failover`

That works fine for the first scenario.

`event->labels->>device_type=is.null`

works fine for the second scenario. But how do I combine them to an OR statement?

I've tried:

`or=(event->labels->>device_type=is.null,event->labels->>device_type=eq.failover)`

`event->labels->>device_type=or(eq.failover,is.null)`

`event->labels->>device_type.or=(eq.failover,is.null)`

But all of these just return a 400 bad request error...

Any idea how to combine a JSON match with an OR statement in postgrest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request should be:

```
or=(event->labels->>device_type.is.null,event->labels->>device_type.eq.failover)
```

Basically, use dot `.`(instead of `=`) as a separator inside the `or` querystring param.